# SwiftUI - onCommit equivalent for TextEditor

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there an onCommit equivalent for TextEditor in SwiftUI? I want to dismiss the keyboard by using self.endEditing and this can easily be achieved with text fields by using `onCommit`.

I've tried using the `onTapGesture` method where i call `UIApplication.self.endEditing()` when a user taps anywhere outside the text field, however this causes some unwanted bugs with my existing segmented picker so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Would you be looking for `.onSubmit`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var fullText: String = "This is some editable text..."
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            TextEditor(text: $fullText)
        }.onTapGesture {
            closeView()
        }
        
    }
    
    func closeView() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(
            #selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder),
            to: nil,
            from: nil,
            for: nil
        )
    }
}

let view = TestView()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

Give it a go with `resignFirstResponder`

Answer (score -1):

### SwiftUI - Dismiss the keyboard on TextEditor

1. When user press enter or creates a new line.

```
TextEditor(text: $text)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onChange(of: text) { string in
                if string.last == "\n"
                {
                    text.removeLast()
                    isFocused = false
                }
            }
```

2. When user taps.

```
TextEditor(text: $text)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onTapGesture {
                isFocused ? (isFocused = false) : (isFocused = true)
            }
```

Also you can create a function to hide keyboard and replace it where focus assignation is. But I think is not necessary here.

Comment: Estuardo, your `.onChange` code won't do anything when I put a cursor somewhere in the middle of the text I've entered and tap on return.